# Robolectric 3 GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException

Tags: android, junit, google-play-services, robolectric, android-testing

I've just started to use Robolectric and wanted to know how to resolve **Google Play Services**. I'm using **Robolectric 3 RC2**, and my gradle is as follow :

**build.bradle**

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
testCompile ("org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0-rc2"){
    exclude module: 'commons-logging'
    exclude module: 'httpclient'
}
testCompile ("org.robolectric:shadows-play-services:3.0-rc2"){
    exclude module: 'commons-logging'
    exclude module: 'httpclient'
}
testCompile 'com.squareup.okhttp:mockwebserver:1.2.1'
```

I'm running a method from my project to get json from an API. When calling it, I pass the advertising ID :

```
        AdvertisingIdClient.Info adInfo = null;
        try {
            adInfo = AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(mContext);
        } catch (IOException |
                GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException |
                GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
            // Unrecoverable error connecting to Google Play services (e.g.,
            // the old version of the service doesn't support getting AdvertisingId).
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The main part of my test is :

```
@Test(timeout = 7000)
public void jsonLoading() {
    try {
        client.loadData(this);
    } catch (Exception e){
        ex = e;
    }

    assertNull(ex);

    //wait for task code
    ShadowApplication.runBackgroundTasks();
```

Each time I run the test, I've got the `GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException` (from `e.printStackTrace();`) and I'm unable to **solve it** AND to **assert** it so the test will not pass.

I've haven't find any clue to debug my code.

Comment: Just to check - do you run test as instrumental or jvm test?

Comment: @EugenMartynov jvm test (Unit Test)

Comment: @HugoGresse Can you please check out my answer?

Comment: @JaredBurrows I will in time, I've other stuff to manage currently

Comment: @HugoGresse What is the status of this?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this the other day.

### Use:

```
testCompile 'org.robolectric:shadows-play-services:3.0'
testCompile 'org.robolectric:shadows-support-v4:3.0'
```

### And see this example:

```
public class TestBase {

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        // Turn off Google Analytics - Does not need to work anymore
        final ShadowApplication shadowApplication = Shadows.shadowOf(RuntimeEnvironment.application);
        shadowApplication.declareActionUnbindable("com.google.android.gms.analytics.service.START");

        // Force success
       ShadowGooglePlayServicesUtil.setIsGooglePlayServicesAvailable(ConnectionResult.SUCCESS);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {

    }
}

public MyTestClass extends TestBase {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

For folks trying to use GoogleApiAvailability with Robolectric...

**gradle**

```
dependencies {
  testApi 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.6.1'
  testApi 'org.robolectric:shadows-playservices:3.6.1'
}
```

**Code**

```
public class TestBase {

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        final ShadowGoogleApiAvailability shadowGoogleApiAvailability
                = Shadows.shadowOf(GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance());
        shadowGoogleApiAvailability.setIsGooglePlayServicesAvailable(ConnectionResult.SUCCESS);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    }
}

public MyTestClass extends TestBase {
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can use Google play services with robolectric, you will need shadows.

Comment: Please see my answer.