# Error: Cannot access VectorDrawable in Robolectric

Tags: android, junit, mockito, robolectric, powermockito

I tried to upgrade robolectric version in my test to 3.3.2. But it just gives me this error
`cannot access VectorDrawable ShadowActivity shadowActivity = org.robolectric.Shadows.shadowOf(testContext);
class file for android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable not found`

This is my test code

`Activity testContext;
testContext = Robolectric.buildActivity(Activity.class).get();
ShadowActivity shadowActivity = org.robolectric.Shadows.shadowOf(testContext);`

Build.gradle

```
testCompile libs['powermock-api-mockito-2']
testCompile libs['powermock-module-junit4-2']
testCompile(group: 'org.robolectric', name: 'robolectric', version:'3.3.2')
testCompile(group: 'org.robolectric', name: 'shadows-support-v4', version:'3.1.2')
    testCompile(group: 'org.robolectric', name: 'shadows-core-v23', version:'3.1.2')
    testCompile(group: 'org.robolectric', name: 'shadows-multidex', version:'3.1.2')
```

Could you please let me know what am I doing wrong? This error just doesn't make sense because I am not drawing or anything in my test code. Then why it gives me the error for VectorDrawable?

Thanks in Adavance

Comment: Can you please try a `gradlew --refresh-dependencies` and also deleting the `~\.m2` directory to cause the dependencies for Robolectric to download again? The shadow classes are stored in the `~\.m2` so you might have out of date ones there

Comment: tried, but still the same exception!

Comment: Are you doing something with VectorDrawable in your Application subclass?

Comment: Nope. That's the surprise for me, that I am not doing anything with the VectorDrawable then why it's giving me this error!!

In fact, i have couple of instances of Shadows.shadowof() and all are giving weird exceptions.
Other than this VectorDrawable exception, I got `cannot access usermanager` then `cannot access TelecomManager` ...

Comment: What version of mockito are you using?

Comment: For Mockito, `testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.5"` 
For PowerMockito `org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.7.0`

Comment: That's a very old version of Mockito and I doubt it will work any more. Can you try switching to `testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.8.9'` or whatever the latest version is. You can also make sure that powermock is up to date

Comment: for Mockito, I can upgraded only to 2.8.47 `org.mockito:mockito-core:2.8.47` and PowerMockito is the latest one. Still same exception

Comment: What `sdk` are you configuring for your Robolectric test runner?

Comment: tried with all 3 sdks, 18, 21 & 23

Comment: Have you tried invalidate cache/restart? I don't really have any more ideas

Comment: Tried, same exception.. :(

Comment: is there any other way to replace the use of Shadows with some other object?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31632827/5241933) help for that?

Comment: Can you switch off PowerMock? And try this particular test?

Comment: okay, let me try that..!